# Stop auto equipping alcohol!

Tags: dead-island

I am playing Dead Island on the PC.  Many NPCs want alcohol for various purposes, so I want to collect it when I see them laying around.

But when I do this, the game seems to switch my current weapon with alcohol.  If I am not paying attention, or if I am quickly attacked after collecting the alcohol, I use the alcohol instead of attacking with my machete/knife like I intended.  This is extremely frustrating, since I waste alcohol, and I incur needless damage while a zombie chews on my body while I am switching to a different weapon.

Please help me make this STOP.  I do not ever want to equip alcohol after picking it up.

Comment: I sometimes find I've auto-equipped alcohol in real life. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Alex that's a feature, where can I get a copy?

Answer (score 5):

You equip equippable items by holding the button down rather than tapping it to pick them up.  The game is often too eager to do this as well, sometimes you barely have to hold the button at all. Try to just tap the button faster, as in, reduce the amount of time you have the button actually pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Wielding a weapon while alcohol is in the weapon wheel does not cause alcohol to be auto-equipped upon pick-up. However, while wielding fists (empty hands), it is the case.

This recommendation goes along with what Ender recommends, i.e. lessening the amount of time that you hold down the use button to pick up equippables.